# So+simple past verb+subject?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What is the grammatical structure and meaning of the bolded sentence:

> “Critical thinking” was the watchword for what the better teachers supposedly taught in the better schools. **So ran one account**. According to another, ...

Answer (score -2):

"So ran one account ..." is a sentence fragment, not a complete sentence, that indicates a direct quotation.  You can place it at the start of the sentence:

> **So ran one account**: "'Critical thinking' was the watchword for ..."

Or after the quote:

> "'Critical thinking' was the watchword ..." -- or at least, **so ran one account**.  According to another ...

However this expression can be confusing and overly formal/dramatic.  If you must use it, it's important to use the right punctuation to properly distinguish each part of the sentence.

I would not recommend using it in ordinary writing, since there are simpler, less theatrical ways to say the same thing, at least until you become more familiar with writing English to evoke an emotional response.

Comment: I think you're misled by the fronted adverb, and confusing it with the conjunctive/prepositional use of the word in other contexts: *So ran one account* is a complete sentence: "One account ran *in this manner*."

Comment: Agreed with @StoneyB.  It's akin to "So it goes."

Comment: Thanks a lot
1. How can I realize in similar cases, "so" is a conjunction/preposition or an adverb (as @StoneyB and stangdon said)?
2. What is the grammatical law for displacement of subject and verb, in this sentence?

Comment: @user52346 My answer may not be entirely correct.  "So it goes" is a complete sentence, and "so ran one account" is apparently similar.

Comment: Thanks again​.      But what do you think about my last two questions? (Whether you were right about first question or not)?